# Lightning button action in VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, button, svg-icon

I have below commandbutton that works fine for me. When I try to convert to lightning buttons it simply just reloads the page and does nothing as expected like calling the pagereference method and return values accordingly.

**Command Button**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Download XML" action="{!getProcessing}" />
```

**Lightning Button**

```
 <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" action="{!Processing}">Button</button>
```

Can someone please let me know where I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an HTML button and unfortunately, you can't call apex code using HTML buttons.

Now you have few options here.

As you are using custom CSS, you can set `StandardStylesheet = false` and add the CSS in Apex:commandButton.

```
<apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand" value="Download XML" action="{!getProcessing}" />
```

Or you need to call actionfunction and from there you can call the controller.

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="actfun()">Button</button>
<apex:actionfunction name="actfun" action="{!Processing}" />
```

Comment: I tried both the cases but it just reloads the page when i add styleclass to command button.

Comment: Also I am unable to add any lightning icon to the button. it simply not showing.

Comment: @Testing_SFDC To stop reloading you need to set defender. Also did you set standard stylesheet false?

Comment: got it with onclick="return actfun();" ! Thanks. But I can't add svg icons to the button. It simply not showing up. Can you please help?

Comment: @Testing_SFDC It would be better if you post a new question with that. Add screenshots as well.